# How to make Recycler View to behave like PlayStore Recycler Views

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, user-experience

I have a simple RecyclerView, I want to make it behave like PlayStore recycler view on horizontal scrolling. By PlayStore behaviour, I mean when ever scrolled to a position it either rewinds back to the same element or change to another position. The Screen Cast have it clearly.

Here is a full width implementation

[image]

And another one, a relatively small width implementation. both from PlayStore.

[image]

My simple Recycler is the common one.,

The layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">
  
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">
  
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
  
    </LinearLayout>
  
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter

```
class CustomAdapter(private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_design, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview)
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }
}
```

activity

```
val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
val data = ArrayList<ItemsViewModel>()
val adapter = CustomAdapter(data)
recyclerview.adapter = adapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tool you are looking for is called SnapHelper.

Java way:

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

Kotlin way:

```
val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView)
```

After this it most likely should work as in app store.